# Am I not getting the concept of flagging?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Recently I started to flag low level content on SO and sometimes the content which in my opinion is clearly unsuitable is declined. So I would like to understand whether it is me not getting the point of flags, or someone else.

Please take a look at some of content that was flagged, but was declined. I would be happy if someone can explain me the reason, so what I would not do this mistake next time.

- [just 2 links. No explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css/20051036#20051036)
- [duplicate of accepted answer. No value being add.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193385/how-to-display-html-title-attribute-in-multiple-lines-in-firefox/5193514#5193514)
- [extremely bad answer. User want to delete it, but can not because it is accepted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961502/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-build-the-package-json-file-for-node-js-projects/10001767#10001767)
- [useless comment. Yes it has 40 upvotes, but it is not constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome/3011656#3011656)
- [two link only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification/19303766#19303766) answers [with no explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification/22700272#22700272)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It might be helpful if you clearly stated what you flagged it as.

Answer (score 4):

> just 2 links. No explanation

I see an explanation: "I had a new problem which has been solved by `zoom: 1` caused by using `SlideUp()`across IE 6 to IE10." This explanation appears *before* the links, so it's not exactly missable.

> duplicate of accepted answer. No value being add.

It was posted at around the same time. It's not really fair to punish users who happen to have been writing the same answer at the same time as one another. As a general rule of thumb, you should only flag duplicate answers when:

- they are **exact** copies of other answers with no changes in wording or formatting, either to the same question, or elsewhere without attribution (these are plagiarized posts), or
- they were posted *very* late, e.g. several months or years later than the rest of the answers, and do not add any value to the existing answers.

> extremely bad answer. User want to delete it, but can not because it is accepted.

OK, but that's not what your flag said. For the record, this is your flag message: "This is not even close to a normal answer."

In any case, it looks like the answerer updated their answer to match the correct answer so it won't mislead future readers. The extremely low score still rubs me the wrong way, since editing an answer doesn't necessarily invalidate downvotes nor notify voters of the edit, so I *might* be inclined to just put it out of its misery.

> useless comment. Yes it has 40 upvotes, but it is not constructive

It's using a figure of speech to explain how the answer relates to the question. Sure, it's tongue-in-cheek, but I wouldn't say that it's completely meaningless or unhelpful.

> two link only answers with no explanations

Those are links to tools, which is exactly what the question asked for. You can't blame an answerer for answering a question if the question itself specifically asks for link-only answers. The problem lies in the question; if the question isn't already closed, you should vote to close the question instead.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. As I understood all these answers/comments/questions are valid and considered ok on SO?

Comment: @Salvador Dali: I would say that they aren't bad enough that they absolutely need deleting, or they point to other problems but aren't problems in themselves (like the last two link answers for example).