# Interesting "undownvoted" occurrence on my account

Tags: discussion, answers, serial-voting

Logged on this am and noticed this:

[image]

I'm guessing the ["auto downvote robot thing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296276/undownvoted-rather-than-removed-in-reputation-history) has undone these 3 downvotes.

I'm guessing it thinks I was serially voting, which I suppose I was as each of these downvotes was for one user in a short period of time. What it seems not to have noticed is that each one of these answers is by one person on one question and are essentially saying the same or similar things. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377548/542251) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377572/542251) [linkz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377767/542251).

I appreciate that this is an edge case but possibly worth tweaking the algorithm? Or am I serial voting here and shouldn't have? I mean I downvoted these because all 3 are a bit rubbish.

BTW I considered flagging these but they are answers, they're not very good and he's answered the same question 4 times (ones already deleted) which isn't technically against the rules. So without having a good reason to flag them I simply downvoted them.

Comment: Looks like the answerer tried to improve their answer - but did not understand editing, so posted other answers instead. (Also note that it's old, it's from 2010. Answerer last seen in June this year, might still be around).

Comment: Yes, I did add a comment to this effect

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What it seems not to have noticed is that each one of these answers is by one person on one question and are essentially saying the same or similar things. Here's some linkz.

I don't think it's sophisticated enough to be able to tell that those three are all "essentially saying the same or similar things". They don't even *look* remotely similar to the untrained eye.

As you note, this is an edge case. There is quite simply nothing you can do in the area of casting up or down votes. However since you say that the answers were mostly just saying the same thing, there's nothing wrong with raising a flag explaining the situation. I looked at them and one of them is clearly no longer needed, so I deleted it.

(No, Meta, this is not a sign that we need a "no longer needed" canned flag for answers. Don't get any funny ideas.)

Comment: Hey, I just got a funny idea! What if we had a flag for duplicate/plagiarized answers? To be used in cases where someone posts a late answer that is either copy/pasta of an existing answer, or a "light version" of an existing answer. These flags would go into the late answer review queue. Ideally the person raising the flag would have some means to point out which answer that is being plagiarised. I'm actually serious here, this is very common, particularly under questions with lots of attention. The only tool user moderators have against this is "protect", which doesn't do much good at all.

Comment: @Lundin: I can see that getting somewhere, but I think it'll depend on how effective reviewers are, or will be, at catching stolen content in the Late Answers queue. Right now there are no good ways of telling if content is stolen, other than by brute-forcing every answer in the queue into a Google search. After all, a stolen answer often just looks like a really nicely written answer that happened to be late. As much as I'd love if every reviewer did that, I'm not sure if it's a realistic expectation to have.

Comment: They are not necessarily consciously stolen, but are posted by very confused users. Usually it goes like this: there's some question, someone writes a great answer "Put the foo in the bar. `<lots of examples and details>`". Lots of attention, lots of up-votes. Then 5 years later, user Herp Derp shows up and posts "Hey, you need to put the foo in the bar. Let me know if this fixed the problem.". Without any details. These kind of answers add nothing that wasn't already said and should be deleted.

Comment: @Lundin A proposal to add a "plagiarized" flag is actually something that I'm working on, along with a general tweak of the flagging choices. I've been holding off on posting a Meta question since there's been a lot of activity recently (mod election, sunsetting of Documentation, etc.), but long story short is I think that's a good idea. I don't think it should go to the Late Answers queue, though. Moderators should be the ones to deal with plagiarism.

Comment: @Lundin: That's not plagiarism, then. Late duplicate answers are covered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267418/am-i-not-getting-the-concept-of-flagging/267419#267419) (vs plagiarism) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284026/what-should-we-do-when-a-question-is-getting-a-lot-of-redundant-answers/284028#284028). Totally handleable by a review queue. Content that is strictly plagiarized is subject to moderator action.

Comment: @BoltClock, you say "handleable by a review queue," but in your first link, you say _not to bug mods_ unless it is unmistakably willful plagiarism. This corresponds to my [somewhat grudging synopsis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342211/#comment484760_342216) of [@CodyGray's current approach.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342216/) Your second link says "go ahead and mod-flag," which I admit I like better but in practice [doesn't often work.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275958/)